# How can I plot this figure?

Tags: plotting

I have the formula, the renyi entropy $\frac{1}{1-q}ln(\sum_{i=1}^Np_i^q)$, and the figure I haven't seen before, is it the ContourPlot for N=3 (the condition is $0\le p_1\le1,0\le p_2\le1,p_1+p_2+p_3=1$)?[image]

I only get this:

```
q = 2;
S1 = 1/(1 - q) Log[p1^q + p2^q + (1 - p2 - p1)^q];
ContourPlot[S1, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We need to use ternary coordinate,that is we need to mapping the set

```
{p1,p2,p3}, p1+p2+p3==1,p1>0,p2>0,p3>0
```

to `{x,y}` coordinate.

```
Clear[q, f, ternary, inverseternary, reg, inversereg];
q = 2;
f[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] = 1/(1 - q) Log[p1^q + p2^q + p3^q];
ternary[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] = {p1 + 1/2 p2, Sqrt[3]/2 p2};
inverseternary[{x_, y_}] = {p1, p2, p3} /. 
   Solve[{x == p2 + 1/2 p3, y == Sqrt[3]/2 p3, 
      p1 + p2 + p3 == 1}, {p1, p2, p3}][[1]];
reg = ImplicitRegion[{p1 > 0, p2 > 0, p3 > 0, p1 + p2 + p3 == 1}, {p1,
     p2, p3}];
inversereg = TransformedRegion[reg, ternary];
ContourPlot[f[inverseternary[{x, y}]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ inversereg], 
 Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! You are so great!

Comment: What if I change the function with "-p1 Log[p1] - p2 Log[p2] - p3 Log[p3] + Log[p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2]", should I change "p2 + 1/2 p3, Sqrt[3]/2 p3"?

Comment: @KarryMa  For the coordinate transformation about ternary, we can read the document `ref/TernaryListPlot` or online https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TernaryListPlot.html

Comment: So the picture I plot is in the rectangular coordinates and this is in barycentric coordinate system, right?

Comment: @KarryMa Yes,you are right.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Why I can't get the figure you plot by your code?

Comment: I used a 12.0 The test failed. I replaced it with a 13. Thank you!!!

Comment: @KarryMa  I have updated the code, use `Solve` instead of `SolveValues`, now it work for 12.0

Comment: YES!!! You are so nice! :)